# Unable to eliminate Runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy several data from a table on a different sheet, to a new table on another sheet. My structure is like:

[image]

These are the steps that me and Mr. @QHarr have tried:

1. Checked the objects and values exist
2. Tried running the codes line by line
3. Activate sheets and re-arranging the codes

None worked so far:

[image]

Here is my current codes:

```
Private Sub cmdedit_Click()
If MsgBox("Transfer selected asset to " & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "?", vbYesNo, "CONFIRMATION") = vbYes Then

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wsendRow As Range
Dim wsendRow1 As Range
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lr As ListRow

Set ws = Sheets("FIELD OFFICE DATABASE")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Transferred Items")
Set lo = ws1.ListObjects("table3")
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add

Set wsendRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
'Set wsendRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

ws.Activate

Range("B2").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Address = wsendRow.Address

If ActiveCell.Value = Me.cmbemn.Text Then
'ws1.Unprotect "321321"
'ws1.Activate
lr.Range(1, 1).Value = Me.cmbemn.Text 'error appears on this line. if I place a comment here, the error will just move on the next line.
lr.Range(1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
lr.Range(1, 3).Value = Me.txttype.Text
lr.Range(1, 4).Value = Me.txtmodel.Text
lr.Range(1, 5).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
lr.Range(1, 6).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
lr.Range(1, 7).Value = Me.txtpurdate.Text
lr.Range(1, 8).Value = Me.txtprice.Text
lr.Range(1, 9).Value = Me.txtcon.Text
lr.Range(1, 10).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
lr.Range(1, 11).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value
lr.Range(1, 12).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Text
lr.Range(1, 13).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
lr.Range(1, 14).Value = Date
lr.Range(1, 15).Value = ws.Range("A13").Value
lr.Range(1, 16).Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
Exit Do
Exit Sub
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop
End If
End Sub
```

Codes never worked. Also to note, this question is in reference to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397741/excel-crash-when-copying-row-through-vba/48397983?noredirect=1#comment84028411_48397983), (which took a lot of comments from me and Mr. QHarr) until he suggested that I should ask another question instead.

I hope someone can help me figure this out.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select)

Comment: @Matt, yes, and also the one who's helping me, still cant figure it out. I've also deleted the whole sheet and created a new one. Still no luck

Comment: Have you checked the References? Sometimes a MISSING reference can cause odd behaviour! Tools>References

Comment: You need to do the unprotect **before** inserting the new `ListRow`. Do `ws1.Unprotect "321321"` before `Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add`.

Comment: `lr.Range(1, 1).Value`?, is it possible the code thinks range should be cells.?  Range() is normally indicated by `range("A1")` and cells uses, `cells(1,1)`

Comment: @Davesexcel:  `lr.Range(1, 1).Value` is the shorter form for `lr.Range.Item(1, 1).Value`. Both should work. I really suspect that it is a issue with protect/unprotect. In a protected sheet the new `ListRow` will be created but does not having any `Range`. So using the `Range` will fail later.

Comment: @AxelRichter, Your suggestion fixed my problem. I didn't thought of that solution because I was informed that protecting the sheet this way "ws1.Protect password:="321321", UserInterfaceOnly:=true", I will be able to do anything to the sheet without un-protecting it. Anyways, thank you very much for your help!